# Passing list from perl to Python and check return value

Tags: python, perl

I have written following script in perl and trying to  pass python.

Input : D1 and D2 are array and plotanalysis is python script

```
my @D1=([],[]);
my @D2=([],[]);
my $cmd="plotanalysis -d1 @D1 -d2 @D2";
print STDERR "***Info : plotanalysis command $cmd\n";
if(system($cmd)!=0)
{
  print STDERR "plotanalysis did not run";
}
```

Expecting : I was expecting array will pass to python script But getting following info

Getting following line

```
plotanalysis command plotanalysis -d1 ARRAY(0x873b58) ARRAY(0x873b88) -d2 ARRAY(0xa3ffa0) ARRAY(0xa3ffd0)
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `plotanalysis -d1 ARRAY(0x873b58) ARRAY(0x873b88) -d2 ARRAY(0xa3ffa0) ARRAY(0xa3ffd0)'
```

Any input/suggestion to fix issue. I also need to capture return value from python script. may i know how can be handle?

In python script, I have make as string

```
def parse_args(args):
    """Parse the argument"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='check function',
                                     epilog="""
                                     for reporting any issue""")
    parser.add_argument('-d1', '-data1', dest='data_1', required=True,
                        nargs = "*",
                        help = "x and y data for calculation")
    parser.add_argument('-d2', '-data2', dest='data_2', required=True,
                        nargs = "*",
                        help = "x and y data for calculation")
    args = parser.parse_args(args)
    return args
def main(args):
    """Invoke main functionality"""
    print (args)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(parse_args(sys.argv[1:])))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done following update which help me get desired value

```
my $cmd="plotanalysis -d1 '@{$D1[1]}' -d2 '@{$D2[1]}'";
print STDERR "***Info : plotanalysis command $cmd\n";
if(system($cmd)!=0)
{
  print STDERR "plotanalysis did not run";
}
```